Why are my comments delated from other answers
I recently asked a question on workplace stackexchange which initiated some debate in my original question and in answers as well. I wanted to clear my stand and I put lot of comments on all the answers as well. However, now that I see after few days all my comments are removed from other answers (all comments posted by me in every single answer is gone). Is there a policy to remove OP's comments from the answers? I have been extremely respectful in all my comments and clarified multiple issues related to the question. Without those comments, those answers look irrelevant and in many ways unfair on me.

Comments are meant to be ephemeral, they are often deleted.

There's no such policy.
Looking at the post in question.. most of the comment deletions (not all of which were yours by the way) seem to be coming from being flagged as "No longer needed", I'm not the mod who actioned the flags, and while there's nothing especially objectionable about the comments (they're a touch argumentative but civil) comments are ephemeral and you shouldn't count on them being there forever.

Thanks for clarification. However, I disagree because only my comments are removed from some answers while other commentary is retained.  Removing my comments which explains or clarifies the key assumptions and letting other comments stay which makes the assumptions even worse seems very biased.
This was certainly a sour experience.

Not only your comments were removed, and "letting other comments stay" mischaracterises the process somewhat, it's unlikely the mod in question went through each comment thinking "keep, delete, keep, delete" but instead responded to the flags. If there's commentary you object to, whether it's no longer needed or irrelevant or unfriendly/rude flag it to us and we'll respond.

I do not agree with you at all and I think there is deeper attitude issue related to country and culture. Do not want to extend that discussion but I  am done with this site. Thanks for your clarification.
